# Any Chrome extention to hide seleted GitHub issue and remember rule when back?

Tags: google-chrome, github, annotations, issue-tracking

Sometimes I need review issues in a GitHub repo to learn examples and experience.

Since there are so many issues, I want to mark some of the issues as useless, some are importance or add some icon to that.

Note: **What I want is not note annotation tool!** I would like mark issue on the issue list, and the marker need remember its position.

Issue list grows, so normal annotation tool don't support.